# Need a technical info on keyboard-playback.

Tags: keyboard

Recently, i heard a term "keyboard playback" at work. I tried to find something on google but there is not a lot of info. If anyone could give any info, i would be forever grateful.

JFK

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=keyboard+playback  First few results answer your question.

Comment: You'll need to give us more context.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard playback sounds a lot like a less technical term for "[macro recording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_recorder)".

> A macro recorder is a piece of software that records user actions for **playback** at a later time. The main advantage of using a macro recorder is that it allows a user to easily perform complex operations much faster and with less effort without requiring custom computer programming or scripting.

There's innumerable software that does this - certain high end keyboards and mice allow it as well.